# C++ - Collision response leads to clipping

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to implement a collision detection system, and it is working for the most part, no overlapping (or at most very little overlapping) of characters, and wall collisions. The problem is that i have a bunch of characters following a player and just run into it, and when there are about 15-20 of those characters all pushing at the player, it can lead to the player or other objects being pushed through walls.

My code works as follows, first I update all of the characters, and they check collisions against each other, then I check for any character collisions with the walls. I feel like the problem is that the eventual push of all the characters leads to pushing one or more of the characters large distances, but i'm not sure how to fix the problem. Code below if necessary, a thorough explanation of how to fix this is also sufficient.

Character update/collisions:

```
void CharacterManager::updateAll(float elapsedTime)
{
    for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator i = _characters.begin(); i != _characters.end(); i++) {
        (*i)->update(elapsedTime);
    }
    collisions();
}

void CharacterManager::collisions()
{
    for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator i = _characters.begin(); i != _characters.end(); i++) {
        for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator j = _characters.begin(); j != _characters.end(); j++) {
            if(i == j) continue;
            float xi = (*i)->position().x;
            float yi = (*i)->position().y;
            float xj = (*j)->position().x;
            float yj = (*j)->position().y;
            float dx = xi - xj;
            float dy = yi - yj;
            float distSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            float ri = (*i)->xRect().width/2;
            float rj = (*j)->xRect().width/2;
            if(distSquared < (ri + rj) * (ri + rj)) {
                // fix collisions
                float angle = atan2f(dy,dx);
                float overlap = (ri + rj) - sqrt(distSquared);
                if(xi < xj) {
                    if(yi < yj) {
                        (*i)->position(xi - cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yi - sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                        (*j)->position(xj + cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yj + sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                    } else {
                        (*i)->position(xi - cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yi + sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                        (*j)->position(xj + cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yj - sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(yi < yj) {
                        (*i)->position(xi + cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yi - sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                        (*j)->position(xj - cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yj + sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                    } else {
                        (*i)->position(xi + cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yi + sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                        (*j)->position(xj - cosf(angle) * overlap/2, yj - sinf(angle) * overlap/2);
                    }
                }
                // calc new velocities
                float vxi = (*i)->velocity().x;
                float vyi = (*i)->velocity().y;
                float vxj = (*j)->velocity().x;
                float vyj = (*j)->velocity().y;
                float vx = vxj - vxi;
                float vy = vyj - vyi;
                float dotProduct = dx * vx + dy * vy;
                if(dotProduct >= 0) {

                    float collisionScale = dotProduct / distSquared;
                    float xCollision = dx * collisionScale;
                    float yCollision = dy * collisionScale;
                    float combinedMass = (*i)->weight() + (*j)->weight();
                    float collisionWeightA = 2 * (*j)->weight() / combinedMass;
                    float collisionWeightB = 2 * (*i)->weight() / combinedMass;
                    (*i)->velocity(vxi + collisionWeightA * xCollision, vyi + collisionWeightA * yCollision);
                    (*j)->velocity(vxj - collisionWeightB * xCollision, vyj - collisionWeightB * yCollision);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wall collisions:

```
void Stage::characterCrossCollisions(std::shared_ptr<Character> character)
{
    for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>>::iterator tile = tiles.begin(); tile != tiles.end(); tile++) {
        if(!(*tile)->walkable) {
            sf::Rect<float> cxr = character->xRect();
            sf::Rect<float> cyr = character->yRect();
            sf::Rect<float> tr = (*tile)->getRect();

            if(!(cxr.left > tr.left + tr.width ||
                 cxr.left + cxr.width < tr.left ||
                 cxr.top > tr.top + tr.height ||
                 cxr.top + cxr.height < tr.top)) {
                float ox = 0;
                if(character->position().x > (*tile)->position().x) {
                    ox = cxr.left - (tr.left + tr.width);
                }
                else {
                    ox = cxr.left + cxr.width - tr.left;
                }
                character->position(character->position().x - ox, character->position().y);
            }

            if(!(cyr.left > tr.left + tr.width ||
                 cyr.left + cyr.width < tr.left ||
                 cyr.top > tr.top + tr.height ||
                 cyr.top + cyr.height < tr.top)) {
                float oy = 0;
                if(character->position().y > (*tile)->position().y) {
                    oy = cyr.top - (tr.top + tr.height);
                }
                else {
                    oy = cyr.top + cyr.height - tr.top;
                }
                character->position(character->position().x, character->position().y - oy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you run the collision code for two objects when the two objects intersect each other. Two objects intersect each other if they share at least one point in space. But the problem with this is that **if objects are intersecting that means that there was a collision in the past** and not that there is a collision right now.

*Ideal* collision code should calculate the energy transfer and modify the velocity of the objects at **the exact moment** when the objects touch each other. Good collision code would roll back time and try to find out the moment when the collision happened, calculate the new velocities based on that moment and roll the time forward. However these are rather hard to do and might be overkill for a simple computer game.

The easy but robust solution that I can recommend to you is:

1. move the objects forward
2. check for collision, if no collision repeat from beginning
3. move the objects away from each other until they don't collide proportional to their mass. Since walls don't move you can consider that they have infinite mass and only move the characters
4. recalculate the velocity of the colliding objects after the objects don't intersect anymore
5. repeat

You can also use a constraint like *'objects can never intersect the wall'* and you apply this constraint by checking if a new position is valid when moving the characters. And you only move the character if the new position is valid.

This small example should exemplify validation. Make the position only updatable with the `MoveTo()` method and inside the `MoveTo()` method you can validate the new position and return whether the move was successful. If the move wasn't successful, the caller will probably want to take a different action. (move the object less until exactly the contact position and this would be the perfect opportunity to process the collision)

```
class Character{

    bool MoveTo(float x, float y)
    {
        if (this.isValidPosition(x,y))
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void Update(float deltaTime)
    {
        float new_x = x + velocity_x*deltaTime;
        float new_y = y + velocity_y*deltaTime;

        if (!this.MoveTo(new_x, new_y))
        {
            Console.Write("cannot move " + this + " to the new position, something is already there\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: very interesting, never thought of updating like this, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: At this point, i'm having difficulties with dealing with more than two objects objects that overlap at the same time and how to solve their end positions/velocities.